# Complication not getting installed for Watch App?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I am trying to add complication to watch app (built using Swift UI) but when I select the "Complications" in the Watch app in iPhone it is showing no complications installed on the Watch app yet.

I have created a "ComplicationController" and added necessary code for "CircularSmall" and "ModularLarge" complication. Below is the code

```
class ComplicationController: NSObject, CLKComplicationDataSource {

    func getSupportedTimeTravelDirections(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimeTravelDirections) -> Void) {
        handler([])
    }

    func getCurrentTimelineEntry(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTimelineEntry?) -> Void) {

        if complication.family == .circularSmall
        {

            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText()
            template.textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "12")
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(timelineEntry)

        } else if complication.family == .modularLarge {
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
            template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Main Header")
            template.body2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Main complication")
            template.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Sub complication 1")
            let timelineEntry = CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(), complicationTemplate: template)
            handler(timelineEntry)

        } else {

            handler(nil)
        }
    }

    func getLocalizableSampleTemplate(for complication: CLKComplication, withHandler handler: @escaping (CLKComplicationTemplate?) -> Void)
    {
        switch complication.family
        {
        case .circularSmall:
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText()
            template.textProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "12")

            handler(template)
        case .modularLarge:
            let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
            template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Dummy Header")
            template.body2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Dummy Body")
            template.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "Dummy Body 1")

            handler(template)
        default:
            handler(nil)
        }
    }

}
```

I am using Xcode Version 11.4 (11E146) & Watch OS 6
Attaching screenshots of the Complication Configuration Settings in Xcode.

[image: Complication Configuration in Xcode]

[image: Watch App Complication section screenshot]

Comment: Is it a stand alone watch app or does it have an iOS companion app? Complications for stand alone watch apps do not appear in that list.

Comment: @Paulw11 It is a standalone watch app. But why is it not displaying complication ?

Comment: You should be able to add the complication by editing the watch face. I guess the reason it doesn't show in this list is because you can use this list to offload complications that have been installed as a result of installing the host app on your phone.  That doesn't make sense for a stand alone app

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried from the Watch app as well but its not showing ? Am i missing anything other than the above ?

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks ok (I did not try to run it but have written several static and dynamic complications).Complication templates are installed on first install, then cached.  If you ran your app with no, or with broken complications the first time, new overlays of installs will not refresh them to your new versions.  Here is the drill:

1. On device (watch) or Simulator, delete the app
2. In Xcode, clean build folder
3. if for sim, rebuild and run the Complication Scheme
4. if for device, rebuild and run the std watch Scheme
5. Do not use the Notification Scheme unless you are testing notifications
6. Depending on your currentTimelineEntry calls, you might need to swap to a different face, then swap back and reCustomize with your complication

Good luck

Comment: Can you try breakpointing on the switch statements for the template sample and the current entry to see if they ever get run? Also, you should provide a fill fraction for the CLKComplicationTemplateCircularSmallRingText template. It may be required?

Comment: When the ComplicationController will get called ? Put the breakpoints and tried the methods are not getting called..

Comment: it gets called several times, first at startup to create the sample templates if none exist (that's why to need to completely delete the app from the device or sim each time you change a complication!), Second it gets called every time a scheduled background task fires (sounds like you aren't there yet)

Comment: I guess the complication configuration settings provided in the Xcode is enough to get the methods called. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: The scheme labeled "<yourApp> Watchkit App  (complication)" should be correct. Here is a sample project which might be helpful: https://mackuba.eu/2019/03/06/watchkit-adventure-2-mvc/

Comment: Upon deleting the app and installing again the breakpoints are getting caught. Yes the scheme for complication is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the link will check it.

Answer (score 0):

The complication is showing up on the Watch Face when i select all the supported families. Sharing a sample code from Apple as well which will guide how to handle complications.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/displaying_essential_information_on_a_watch_face

Answer (score 0):

1. Check that your ComplicationController is included in the watch app extension target
2. Run the Complication Scheme and check the logs (console)

If you are getting this error message:

Missing or Invalid Principal Class: (MyAPPExtension.ComplicationController). Please check 'ClockKit Complication - Principal' Class property in WatchKit Extension's Info.plist

Do this:

**I had this problem, only went away when I updated `Info.plist` - `ClockKit Complication - Principal Class` to `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).ComplicationController`**

**ComplicationController was already assigned to Watchkit Extension Target.
Info.plist by default just has ComplicationController value set.**

After that the complications are showing fine!
I think this issue appeared when I updated Xcode to the latest version and it expects the property to be like the above mentioned.